# CGAL:how to divide a segment into many little segments and output the points into a file

Tags: cgal, segment

I have a line segment defined by two points P1 and P2.
I now need to divide its into many parts. For example, 50 Parts.
 and output the points into a file from P1 to P2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, it makes no sense to use CGAL, if that is really all what you want.

It's just: P1 + i * (P2 - P1)/50, for i=0..50